# Section and newcommand in LaTeX's memoir

Tags: macros, memoir

I want to change the section layout. The section layout should start with an § then the number (which should start with 1 instead of 0.0) and then the name of the section.

I have tried to make such a thing by myself:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{libertine}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm, top=3cm, bottom=2cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\newcommand{\titel}{\textbf{\S \vspace{1pt}  \thesection{\textbf{}}} \vspace{1pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\fontsize{38}{40} \selectfont \textbf{Wohnungs -- Mietvertrag}}
\end{center}


\titel{TEST}
\end{document}
```

If it would work correctly, the sectioning would look like this:
**§ 1 TEST**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Could you clarify your question? I'm not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sets up the section format and titling using `memoir` macros. Thanks to Paul Gessler for pointing out that `memoir` (and not just me) uses the standard method for defining the numbering.

Note that it is important to use semantic markup i.e. to use `\maketitle` etc. rather than setting stuff manually or defining your own alternative commands. So you want `\section{}` to do what you want - you don't want to define an alternative command if you can help it.

It would be better to use `memoir`'s facilities for adjusting the layout rather than `geometry` etc. I'm not actually sure what purpose your use of `memoir` is serving. If you don't want its facilities, it would be better to use a standard class such as `book` in conjunction with `geometry` etc.

You almost certainly do not want to just set `\parindent` to zero since you will have no indication of new paragraphs. See `memoir`'s documentation for options. (If you go with `book`, try the `parskip` package.)

Note that `\textbf{}` sets a string consisting of zero characters in bold font. That is, it does nothing. At least, it does nothing of the kind you probably want. `\bfseries` switches to bold, and is presumably what you intended.

`memoir` has somewhat different section divisions than the standard classes. Especially, it differs for articles. If you are not using chapters, you probably want to pass `article` to the class but you probably want to use `\chapter` instead of `\section` as well. (That is, you probably want `\chapter` to create sections.) Again, see `memoir`'s documentation for details.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, ngerman]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[left=30mm, right=20mm, top=3cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}% Better to use memoir's page layout
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}% See the documentation for why you shouldn't do this
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setsecnumformat{\S\thinspace \csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\fontsize{38}{40}\bfseries}

\title{Wohnungs -- Mietvertrag}
\author{Some Body}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image: adjusted title and sectioning]

Comment: The `memoir` docs use the standard methods for the numbering redefinition. But (as shown in the documentation), `\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` is perhaps more appropriate since the numbering shouldn't contain `\par`. (I only know this because I was about to post a nearly identical answer `:-)`.)

Comment: @PaulGessler Thanks. You are right about that. I never remember those consistently. Sorry about the answer :(.

Answer (score 2):

In memoir you can use the `article` option in order to have chapters that look like sections in an article class, but without loosing a sectioning level.

For add `\S` before the number can be solved with a redefinition of `\chapternamenum`. An example with only the relevant code:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{\bfseries\Large\S\,}
\title{Wohnungs -- Mietvertrag}
\author{Some Body}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{TEST}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]